# Using Hibernate's Criteria API, can I use concat with ilike restrictions?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, concatenation, hibernate-criteria

Intuitively, what I want to do is something like this:

```
Restrictions.ilike("concat(user.firstName, ' ', user.lastName)",
    text.toLowerCase() + "%")
```

However, I know that this won't work, because `concat(user.firstName, ' ', user.lastName)` is not a property that Hibernate understands, even though this is what I would have typed in a regular SQL statement as part of the where clause.

Is there any easy way to make this where restriction with Hibernate Criteria API, or do I have to fall back on good-old HSQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to define `fullName` property in your `User` class.

```
@Formula(value="first_name || ' ' || last_name")
private String fullName;
```

And then use that filed in `Criteria`,

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("fullName", text.toLowerCase() + "%"));
```

Comment: This solution worked. For those that use hsqldb and mysql together, you may want to use this formula: `ltrim(concat(concat(first_name, ' '), last_name))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little floppy on SQL so the statement may not be 100% accurate.

Obviously, this isn't an `ilike` but if you want to use SQL, why not use a `sqlRestriction` instead with a parameter?

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("select * from user where concat(user.firstName, ' ', user.lastName) like ?", text.toLowerCase() + "%", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
```

I assume the goal is to be able to make a portable Restriction, in which case, this can sub in for your attempted ilike.